# How can i refer to a Modal Window in Dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've gotten hundreds of aids from this site. thanks. This is my first question.
Which object is a modal window (alert popup) into the Dom. How can i refer it? How can i know if open or closed? Something like this: if (alertPopup is open) {..code...}
My code is this (i use jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var myButton = $('#mybutton')

     myButton.click(function(){
        if ($('#myinput').val() == '') {
            alert('input Empty!');
        } else {
            // More code.
        }

     });

     $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) myButton.trigger('click');
     })
});
</script>

<body>
    <input id="myinput" />
    <button id="mybutton">Show alert</button>
</body>
```

The purpose of the code is trigger up the event 'click' on the button whith key 'enter'. It works, but when i close the popup, again with key 'enter', the popup comes again an again. I need to disable event 'click' of my button or unbind the trigger action when the popup is displayed.
I would't like to make my own modal windows.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `"I've gotten hundreds of aids from this site"`... sorry, but I think you maybe using the site wrong. You must have stumbled upon the backdoor

Comment: [It works fine in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Bvb/), what browser are you using? And I don't believe you can reference the alert popup, it is not part of the DOM, it is a browser implemented feature

Comment: I use firefox 26 and Chrome 32 and others. Don't work for me anyway. Ok, the alert window is not into the Dom. I'll look for another strategy. thanks a lot. Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the handler to its own function and programmatically bind/unbind it to the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var myButton = $('#mybutton')

     console.log('whee');

     myButton.click(clickHandler);

     $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) myButton.trigger('click');
     })
});


function clickHandler(){
    $('#mybutton').unbind('click', clickHandler)

    if ($('#myinput').val() == '') {
        alert('input Empty!');
    } else {
        // More code.
    }

}
```

However, it looks more like you're trying to deal with enter buttons in a form submission style. I'd recommend wrapping this whole thing in a form and dealing with it as such.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ruBY4/ for a cleaner form-based solution.

Comment: Thanks, Joe Rinehart. Your suggestion gives solution to part of my problem.Using the clickHandler lose the event 'click' on the button using the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, Joe Rinehart. Your suggestion is very near the solution I need. Using the clickHandler function I lose in forward the event 'click' on the button using the keyboard. And using the form we dont have the event 'clic' for the first time. After 'click' with the mouse works fine. thanks a lot.